# Need help finding the problem in my tic-tac-toe minimax algorithm

Tags: javascript, minimax

I've been building out my tic-tac-toe project for a while now, and I've been running into issues with the unbeatable AI implementation using minimax.

I'm at the point now where the game is almost completely functioning, just that I have one particular square on the grid which is not working as intended. As in, it seems to account for all the outcomes apart from the square at index [8] from the array. It seems to avoid placing itself there or calculating the correct result from it.

```
    const gameBoard = (() => {
        //stores current gameboard as an array
        let array = ['','','','','','','','',''];
        let currentPlayer;
      
        //clears the gameBoard display
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          clearDisplay();
        });
      
        //game display that renders the contents of array to gameboard
        const display = (index, name) => {
          //renders players click to the board, taking in the index of the square
          gameBoard.array.splice(index, 1, name.team);
          innerAnswerText[index].innerText = gameBoard.array[index];
        }
        
        //clears the array and display
        const clearDisplay = () => {
          gameBoard.array = ['','','','','','','','',''];
          innerAnswerText.forEach(text => text.innerText = '');
        }
  
      
        return { display, array, clearDisplay, currentPlayer }
    })();


    //contains all of our game logic
    const game = (() => {    
                
        //starts our game and controls the flow of player vs ai
        const startGame = (index) => {
          //game display that takes in the players click index and renders the             contents of array to gameboard
          gameBoard.display(index, ryan);  
          gameBoard.currentPlayer = 'X';
          if (checkWinner(gameBoard.currentPlayer) !== null) {
            console.log(gameBoard.currentPlayer + ' has won the round!');
            return;
          }
          //computers turn that takes a random choice from the indexes that are           empty and prints it to the board
          
          let compMove;
          let bestScore = -Infinity;
          gameBoard.array.forEach((item,i) => {
            if (gameBoard.array[i] == '') {
              gameBoard.array[i] = 'O';
              let score = minimax(gameBoard.array, 0, false);
              gameBoard.array[i] = '';
              if (score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = score;
                compMove = i;
              }
            }
          });
          gameBoard.display(compMove, computer);
          gameBoard.currentPlayer = 'O';
          if (checkWinner(gameBoard.currentPlayer) !== null) {
            console.log(gameBoard.currentPlayer + ' has won the round!');
            return;
          }
        }
        
        //loop through our html boxes and apply event listeners to each square that will initiate the players round

        boxes.forEach((square, i) => {
          square.onclick = () => {
            startGame(i);
          }
        });   
        
        //checks for a win or a tie using current player variable to check whose turn it is

        const checkWinner = (player) => {
          let winner = null;
          let a = gameBoard.array;
          
          let openSpaces = 0;
          //horizontal win check
          if (a[0] == player && a[1] == player && a[2] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          if (a[3] == player && a[4] == player && a[5] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          if (a[6] == player && a[7] == player && a[8] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          
          //vertical win check
          if (a[0] == player && a[3] == player && a[6] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          if (a[1] == player && a[4] == player && a[7] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          if (a[2] == player && a[5] == player && a[8] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          
          //diagonal win check
          if (a[0] == player && a[4] == player && a[8] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          if (a[2] == player && a[4] == player && a[6] == player) {
            winner = player;
          }
          
          for (let i=0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (gameBoard.array[i] == '') {
              openSpaces++;
            }
          }
          
          if (winner == null && openSpaces == 0) {
            return 'tie';
          }

          return winner;
        }
          
          let scores = {
            X: -10,
            O: 10,
            tie: 0
          }
          
          const minimax = (board, depth, maximizingPlayer) => {
            let result = checkWinner(gameBoard.currentPlayer);
            
            if (result !== null) {
              return scores[result];
            }
            
            if (maximizingPlayer) {
              let bestScore = -Infinity;
              for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
              
                if (board[i] == '') {
                  board[i] = 'X';
                  let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false);
                  board[i] = '';
                  bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
                }
              }
              return bestScore;

            } else {
                let bestScore = Infinity;
                for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                  if (board[i] == '') {
                    board[i] = 'O';
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true);
                    board[i] = '';
                    bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                  }
                }
    
                return bestScore;
            }
          }
    
        
        return { startGame, checkWinner }

        
        
      })();

        //factory function that produces our player object taking in name and team
    const player = (name, team) => {
        
        return { name, team };
    }
    
    const ryan = player('ryan', 'X');
    const computer = player('computer', 'O');
  
  
  
})();
```

I know there is a lot of code here, I'm thinking the problem lies somewhere around our for each or for loops inside the minimax recursion, but I'm unsure. I'll provide my codepen below so you can see the actual game working and you'll see what I mean about that 9th square which isn't working as intended.

https://codepen.io/itswakana/pen/gOeMrym?editors=1111

I appreciate any help you can give! Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your Minimax function you write `for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {` in two places. Shouldn't that 8 be a 9, or put a <= instead of <? Right now you are just checking for index 0 to 7 which is the first 8 squares.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah I did think this and it doesn't seem to make a difference. After switching the loops to 9 instead of 8 'O' just wants to pick in a straight line across. Very strange.

Comment: @Wakana, then there is something else wrong with your minimax/check win/other. Your quesiton was specifically about why it ignores the last square, my answer is why. You can't just post your entire code and expect us to go through it all and find all errors. Post a new question with your new issue, this answer solves this question.

Comment: Yeah I'll try asking a more appropriate question, thanks for the help.